# Transform/redirect internal style to external style

Tags: html, css

I have some script which is using internal style css/html
because it matches some of the code already existing and makes meproblems with the script.

How can I create external style for this internal style code:

```
<style>
[class="skiptranslate"]
{display: none;}

body>div{margin: 1em;}

#google_translate_element{overflow: hidden; height: 1.7em; display: inline-block; margin-bottom: -.65em;}

#align{display: none;}

.goog-te-banner-frame{display: none;}

a.btn, a.btn:visited{-webkit-appearance: button; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; background-color: #357ae8; color: white; padding: .5em; margin: .5em; cursor: pointer;}

#select_lang, #done{display: none;}

h1, h2{margin: 0;}

p{line-height: 1.25em; text-align: left; margin: 0 auto; margin-bottom: 1em;}

#cc{left: 0; width: 90%; opacity: 0.1; margin: 0 5%; position: absolute; top: 0; z-index: -100; transform: scaleY(0.00005); line-height: 0; transform-origin: top left;}

.wrapper{width: 70%; padding-top: 0; margin: 0 auto;}

.progress-bar{width: 100%; background-color: #e0e0e0; padding: 3px; border-radius: 3px; box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(47, 44, 56);}

.progress-bar-fill{display: block; height: 22px; background-color: #ffffff; border-radius: 3px; transition: width 500ms ease-in-out;}

small{position: absolute; bottom: 0px; opacity: .5; margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; left: 0; line-height: 1.5em;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) and (orientation: landscape){

body{font-size: 0.80em;}

}

</style>
```

```
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//google.com">

</head>

<body class="notranslate">

<noscript>

<meta HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;url='https://titles.com/?PageSpeed=noscript'" />

<style>

<!--table,div,span,font,p{display:none} -->

</style>

<div style="display:block">Please click <a href="https://titles.com/?PageSpeed=noscript">here</a> if you are not redirected within a few seconds.</div>

</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to copy that in your external stylesheet and make a little change in style